# How to delete "All items" and "Add New" inside a custom post type menu in Wordpress Admin?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to delete "All items" and "Add New" buttons inside a custom post type menu in Wordpress Admin.

I have a custom post type inside anotoher custom post type made with Tool Types.
But would like to only use the 'mainmenu' post type just as a menu where multiple post types are inside.

Mainmenu (custom post type)
- All items
- Add News
- Submenu (custom post type)
- Submenu (custom post type)

So right now the mainmenu is also a custom post type. I don't mind this as long the All items and Add new buttons are hidden.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the function you'd want to investigate:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_submenu_page

You'd place that demo code in your functions.php file or a functionality plugin, and you'd just need to find the correct menu slug. It's probably just the portion of the URL after your site address for the pages you'd like to remove... So like this:

`remove_submenu_page( 'post-new.php?post_type=your_custom_post_type' );`

It's also worth noting that this method just removes the menu item from the menu.. It doesn't actually prevent someone from accessing those pages if they knew the URL. This might not be a big concern, but if you really want to lock things down you'd also want to check the users permissions for those pages.

Comment: Change it to remove_submenu_page, and you've got a winner!

Comment: Thanks @CarlF.Corneil! Edited

Comment: The remove submenu function demands two arguments, parent slug and submenu slug.